# Create 2 Dimensional array from string with regex

Tags: windows, powershell

I have the following string:

```
@~@MalwareBytes@~@\\192.168.11.1\s$\bla\MBSetup.exe;
\\192.168.11.13\v$\Setups\saaar\MBSetup.exe;
@~@Zoiper@~@\\192.168.11.1\s$\1\Zoiper5_Installer_v5.2.19.exe;
\\192.168.11.1\v$\Setups\Zoiper5_Installer_v5.2.19.exe;
\\192.168.11.3\v$\Setups\Zoiper5_Installer_v5.2.19.exe;
@~@LightShot@~@\\192.168.122.203\v$\1\Zoiper5_Installer_v5.2.19.exe;
\\192.168.120.203\v$\Setups\ha\Zoiper5_Installer_v5.2.19.exe;#####
```

This is actually a program name inside @~@programName@~@ followd by network path's  (each program can get up to 3 network path but could also be 1 or 2)

I would like to Sort the string in the way that an array woule be created with the name of the programs like so:

```
$arr[0] = MalwareBytes
$arr[1] = Zoiper
.
.
```

And in the second dimention is for each program to have array with its pass. for example:

```
$arr[0][0] = \\192.168.11.1\s$\bla\MBSetup.exe; $arr[0][1] = \\192.168.11.13\v$\Setups\saaar\MBSetup.exe
```

The End of file represented by 5 Hashtags.
What would be a good approach to such thing?
Thank you!

Comment: A good approach would be to use two nested foreach loops. First one goes from program name to program name and the nested one iterates over the paths. Use regex lookarounds two inspect your string.

Comment: How can i use RegEx to find the patttern @~@*@~@ where * could be anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theoretically, you can do what you want. However, PowerShell likes to unroll arrays, which prints all of the second dimension elements when only the first dimension element is requested. See below for an example:

```
$array = 1,2,@(3,4)
$array[2][0]
3
$array[2] # Unrolls all second-dimension elements
3
4
```

Given the above limitations, you can do something like the following:

```
# $st is a string of your sample data
$st = @'
@~@MalwareBytes@~@\\192.168.11.1\s$\bla\MBSetup.exe;
\\192.168.11.13\v$\Setups\saaar\MBSetup.exe;
@~@Zoiper@~@\\192.168.11.1\s$\1\Zoiper5_Installer_v5.2.19.exe;
\\192.168.11.1\v$\Setups\Zoiper5_Installer_v5.2.19.exe;
\\192.168.11.3\v$\Setups\Zoiper5_Installer_v5.2.19.exe;
@~@LightShot@~@\\192.168.122.203\v$\1\Zoiper5_Installer_v5.2.19.exe;
\\192.168.120.203\v$\Setups\ha\Zoiper5_Installer_v5.2.19.exe;#####
'@

$ar = [collections.generic.list[collections.generic.list[string]]]@()
$i = -1
($st -split '@~@|;|#+').Trim() -ne '' | Foreach-Object {
    if ($_ -notmatch '\\\\') {
        $ar.Add($_) # Add each program name to first dimension of list
        $i++ # Increase index of first dimension to match latest program's element
    } 
    else {
        $ar[$i].Add($_) # Add paths as second dimension list to most recently updated program's element
    }
}
```

---

**Explanation of Syntax:**

`@''@` represents a here-string. Here-strings are useful for creating blocks of text that you want to treat as a single string. See [About Quoting Rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-7) for more information.

`$ar` is a list of lists, which contain strings. The reason for using a generic list is to allow adding new elements. Syntactically, an array is easier to create, but once created, its size cannot be changed. Lists do not have that limitation.

`-split` operator uses regex matching. When a match is found, that matched string is removed and the remaining string is split into two strings. In other words, one single line with one successful match will be split into two lines. `|` is regex `OR`. `+` means one or more of the previous character. The remaining characters are literal.

`Trim()` is used to remove unnecessary white space surrounding the strings.

Since the split operation creates multiple lines, which is equivalent to an array of strings, `-ne ''` filters out lines with empty strings.

Comment: Wow thank you so much, it works, i now try to understand how. Thanks so much!

Comment: Wehn you declared $st at the beginning, why did you use @' at start and '@ at end if i may ask

Comment: `@''@` is a here-string. It helps when creating a block of text that is intended to be a single string.